# Uncaught ReferenceError: Masonry is not defined

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm woking on my portfolio and I'm using a wordpress theme called Gridly that uses [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). I'm trying to make it so the posts align to the right rather than the left. I came across an option [here](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#isoriginleft) that would allow me to do that by using "isOriginLeft": false but now I just keep getting this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Masonry is not defined" and I'm no closer to getting the posts to align right.

My portfolio is here: brittonhack.com/new/

jQuery is not my strong suit so ANY help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here's the code that keeps producing the error.

```
// masonry code 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#post-area').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector : '.post',
    // options...
  isAnimated: true,
  animationOptions: {
    duration: 400,
    easing: 'linear',
    queue: false
  }

  });
});


// hover code for index  templates
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#post-area .image').hover(
            function() {
                $(this).stop().fadeTo(300, 0.8);
            },
            function() {
                $(this).fadeTo(300, 1.0);
            }
        );  


});


// comment form values
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#comment-form input").focus(function () {
        var origval = $(this).val();    
        $(this).val("");    
        //console.log(origval);
        $("#comment-form input").blur(function () {
            if($(this).val().length === 0 ) {
                $(this).val(origval);   
                origval = null;
            }else{
                origval = null;
            };  
        });
    });
});


// clear text area
$('textarea.comment-input').focus(function() {
   $(this).val('');
});

var container = document.querySelector('#post-area');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  itemSelector: '.post'
});
```

Comment: You do not need multiple jQuery document ready functions, you can combine the logic of the three you have into one; while it is legal to do multiple ready functions, it is confusing to anyone else looking at  your code.

Comment: Where are you referencing the `masonry` script?

Answer (score -1):

You are initializing masonry already at the top of your document:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#post-area').masonry({
        // options
        itemSelector : '.post',
        // options...
    isAnimated: true,
    animationOptions: {
        duration: 400,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false
    }

    });
});
```

And at the end you initialize again (without jQuery):

```
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    itemSelector: '.post'
});
```

The second block is redundant and throws the error. Just delete it.

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of there error but I still can't seem to get the post to flush right? Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to add the option `isOriginLeft: false` directly to the js-masonry options.